# How to update textview in recycler view on button click?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I want to make a like button for my list items whenever i click the like button then the textview should update dynamically.but when i click the button only the last row gets updated and the rest does not change.Please guide me to accomplish this task of making like button in listitems.(I have used likebutton library for like button).

RecyclerViewAdapter.java

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>{

private static final String TAG = "hh";
private String[] names;
private String[] desc;
private Integer[] imageid;
private Context context1;
ImageButton sare;
public ImageView img;
LikeButton likeButton;
TextView tx1;
TextView tx2;
TextView tx3;
TextView tx4;
public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context2,String[] names,String[] desc,Integer[] imageid){
    this.names = names;
    this.desc = desc;
    this.imageid = imageid;
    context1 = context2;
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public LikeButton likeButton;

    public ViewHolder(View v){

        super(v);


    }
}

@Override
public RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){

    View view1 = LayoutInflater.from(context1).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_items,parent,false);

    ViewHolder viewHolder1 = new ViewHolder(view1);
    img = (ImageView) view1.findViewById(R.id.imgview1);
    likeButton = (LikeButton) view1.findViewById(R.id.cvcv);
    tx3 = (TextView)view1.findViewById(R.id.counttxt);
    likeButton.setOnLikeListener(new OnLikeListener() {
        @Override
        public void liked(LikeButton likeButton) {

            int count = Integer.parseInt(tx3.getText().toString());
            Log.d("fgfgfgfgf", String.valueOf(count));
            tx3.setText(String.valueOf(++count));
            //tx3.setText(String.valueOf(Homefragment.countt));
        }
        @Override
        public void unLiked(LikeButton likeButton) {

        }
    });
    return viewHolder1;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder Vholder,final int position){
    if(imageid[position] != null) {
       // img.setImageBitmap(imageid[position]);
    }
    else{
    }
    img.setImageResource(imageid[position]);
    tx1.setText(names[position]);

    Vholder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });

}



@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount(){

    return desc.length;
}

}
```

recycler_view_items.xml

```
<ConstraintLayout>
............
<LikeButton>
....
</LikeButton>
<TextView>
....
</TextView>   
</ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: actually you are doing it all wrong. You should use view holder pattern to accommodate your widgets in adapter layout. you are not using view holder so what happens is only the last like is triggered because it has the same instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    LikeButton likeButton;
    TextView tx1;
    TextView tx2;
    TextView tx3;
    TextView tx4;

    public ViewHolder(View v){
    super(v);
    img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgview1);
    likeButton = (LikeButton) v.findViewById(R.id.cvcv);
    tx3 = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.counttxt);



    }
}
```

Change your OnCreateviewHolder to :-

```
@Override
public RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){

    View view1 = LayoutInflater.from(context1).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_items,parent,false);
    return new ViewHolder(view1);
}
```

OnBindViewHolder to :-

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder Vholder,final int position){
    Vholder.img.setImageResource(imageid[position]);
    Vholder.tx1.setText(names[position]);

    Vholder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
    Vholder.likeButton.setOnLikeListener(new OnLikeListener() {
    @Override
    public void liked(LikeButton likeButton) {

        //Logic
    }
    @Override
    public void unLiked(LikeButton likeButton) {

    }
    });
    }
```

Comment: where should i declare onclick of likebutton oncreationVieHolder or ViewHolder?

Comment: check the Updated Answer

Comment: onBindViewHolder

Answer (score 1):

Replace

`tx3 = (TextView)view1.findViewById(R.id.counttxt);`

with

`TextView tx3 = (TextView)view1.findViewById(R.id.counttxt);`

and

`likeButton = (LikeButton) view1.findViewById(R.id.cvcv);`

with

`LikeButton likeButton = (LikeButton) view1.findViewById(R.id.cvcv);`

In your code you are using the same `instance` of `tx3` and `likebutton`, and it saves the last value, hope this helps

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference                error in BindViewHolder img.setImageResource(imageid[position]);
    tx1.setText(names[position]);

Comment: have you changed something else besides the two lines i mentioned ? @cobraginneshi

Comment: no.. i followed your instructions only but when i replace then there is a error in  img.setImageResource(imageid[position]);
    tx1.setText(names[position]);  and also i have to make tx3 final to access from within inner class